# What's the correct syntax for recipients in Sprout Email?

Tags: plugin-sproutemail

I've got a form creating an entry in a Bookings channel which contains two fields, an Entries field (`eventBooking`) and a Users field (userBooking).

I'm trying to get Sprout Email to send an email to the user selected in `userBooking`. Can anyone help me with the correct syntax please?

I've tried the following which don't seem to work:

`{{ userBooking.first().email }}`
`{{ object.userBooking.first().email }}`
`{{ entry.userBooking.first().email }}`
`{ object.userBooking.first().email }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:
`{{ object.userBooking.first().email }}`

I would check if the problem is with something else.

Comment: Yep, this worked - thanks Carl. I'd forgotten a completely different setting which was stopping it from working; this is the correct syntax. Sorry for the delay in reply, been away for 5 days!